# How to log output to log file using runit

Tags: init, runit

I am running program using runit to run at startup. I want all the output by from the program that is run by runit to be logged to a file.

I have looked at [svlogd](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) but I cannot figure out how to get it running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how to get it running.

In the daemontools family world, log services are just services like any other.  So you run `svlogd` with a `run` program just like you would run a "main" service with a `run` program.

The special things about "log" services are merely that:

- The "log" service directory is located using a symbolic link from (or a straight subdirectory beneath) the "main" service directory.
- Some, but not all, daemontools family toolsets tightly bind "log" and "main" services and operate upon the twain as a unit.  This is to a degree the case with runit.

Otherwise, they are just like everything else.

So make a "log" service to run `svlogd` just like you would make any other service, put it into the right place relative to your "main" service, and set things off.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). ["Logging"](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging).  *The daemontools family*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Gerrit Pape. ["How do I create a new service directory with an appendant log service?"](http://smarden.org/runit/faq.html#createlog).  runit Frequently Asked Questions.
- Daniel J. Bernstein.  ["How do I create a service directory with a log?"](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/faq/create.html#runlog).  daemontools Frequently Asked Questions.

Comment: I cannot save edit, because the change is just 2 characters. Current link to "Logging - the deamontools family" has moved, https://jdebp.uk/FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is to find out where runit files are on your system. Usually it's `/etc/runit/`. There, you'll find a directory called `sv` in which one directory per service is created.

Let's say you want to create a new service called `food`. You would create create a directory called `food` in `/etc/runit/sv/`.

```
# mkdir /etc/runit/sv/food
```

Create a `run` script in `/etc/runit/sv/food`. Let's say that your service's program is an executable at `/opt/bin/foo`. In that case your `run` script will be this.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /opt/bin/foo 2>&1
```

For logging, you should create another directory in `/etc/runit/sv/food` called `log`. And in it another `run` script.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec svlogd -tt <logs-directory>
```

Make sure the `<logs-directory>` exits. And don't forget to make both `run` scripts executables.

```
# chmod +x /etc/runit/sv/food/run
# chmod +x /etc/runit/sv/food/log/run
```

Make a symbolic link of your `food` directory inside `/etc/runit/runsvdir/default`

```
# ln -s /etc/runit/sv/food /etc/runit/runsvdir/default/
```

To manually start/stop your service simply run:

```
# sv start food
# sv stop food
```

Take a loot at this [quick start guide](https://kchard.github.io/runit-quickstart/) for more details.

Notice that unlike the guide, I didn't use `chpst` in my example. In this case the `food` service will run as `root`. Use `chpst` as suggested by the guide if you want your service to run as a specific user.